# Regular expression in C# to replace font-size, font-family, line-height, etc

Tags: c#, regex

Currently I'm eliminating certain formatting tags from HTML strings, and would like to learn enough about regular expressions to be able to replace any formatting.  For starters, this is what I've done, but I'd like it to work with any font size, family, etc:

```
            p.body = p.body.Replace("line-height: 14px;", "");
            p.body = p.body.Replace("font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans;", "");
            p.body = p.body.Replace("font-size: 11px;", "");
```

I'm actually not sure if regex can be used directly inside C# replace or not.

Comment: Why are you eliminating formatting from HTML? If this is to sanitize user input, then you'd be better off with a whitelist.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: it's [not hard to find out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).  (And the answer is "no.")

Comment: Sorry, it was worth the downvote.  Regex looks like garbledy gook to me.  What took you guys 2 minutes would have taken me all day.

Comment: Thom, I have a Content Editable div.  They produce formatting differently depending on what browser is being used.  I need to get rid of all that formatting if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Helper function

```
    public static string RemoveStyle(string html, string style)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(style + "\\s*:.*?;?");

        return regex.Replace(html, string.Empty);
    }
```

Usage:

```
string input = "color: red ; line-height: 10px  ; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans;  ";
input = RemoveStyle(input, "line-height");
input = RemoveStyle(input, "font-family");

// now, input = "color: red ;"
```

Comment: Just a thought: I'm not sure that it's necessary to escape the `-`.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks! (I think it's safe to assume the semicolon is there for my purpose)

Comment: It worked for me with a small change:
Regex regex = new Regex($"{style}\\s*:.*?;");

Answer (score 2):

To use regular expressions in C#, you'll need to use the [Regex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

To match only the specific types of styles you provided, I would try to match:

```
"line-height\\s:.*?;?"
"font-family\\s:.*?;?"
"font-size\\s:.*?;?"
```

or, all together:

```
Regex.Replace(htmlString, "(line-height|font-family|font-size)\\s:.*?;?", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Regex.Replace - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx)

You can strip the entire style attribute.. perhaps like so?

```
Console.Write(Regex.Replace("<td style=\"text-align: right; vertical-align: bottom; width: 368px;\">", " style=\"[^\"]+\"", "")); // outputs "<td>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, let me start off by saying that what you're trying has become the new traveling salesman problem. But, I wanted to reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) in which the post below the accepted answer states you **can** in fact parse HTML with regular expressions - you just don't want to. Please read it because it will help you understand the hurdles.

Now, on to your specific problem.

Let's say you had some HTMl like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="line-height: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-size: 11px;">Some text in the span</span>
</body>
</html>
```

And you wanted to find and replace the `line-height`, you might write a RegEx like this:

```
line-height.+?;
```

And I think you can extrapolate the rest from that RegEx. However, the problem is that you're ***assuming*** that there is a `;` ending that statement always - and with CSS I'm not ***sure*** you can assume that, so that's why everybody tells you it can't be done with regular expressions. But follow along with me for a minute. Now, in C# you might write something like this (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx)):

```
var newString = RegEx.Replace(htmlString, "(line-height:)(.+?)(;)", "$1 $3");
```

The `$1` and `$3` will preserve the first and third captured expressions.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  So far, so good.  I'll deal with any problems as they arise.

Comment: Good point about the "assuming `;`" thing, because I'm pretty sure you can't assume that, actually. For example, I think this is valid HTML: `<span style="line-height: 14px">`.

Comment: @Kache, in fact you're 100% right - I couldn't think of the example but I knew there was one out there!

Comment: Mike, I didn't bother mentioning that the styles I'm removing are added into contenteditable div's by the browser, and not typed in by the user.  I can block the user from adding tags.  I'm hoping (assuming) the browser is consistently adding semicolons after each style.  Neverever got an answer in first.  Otherwise your answer probably would have worked too.

Comment: @Dave, it's not a problem, but I wanted to ensure you understood the hurdles that exist with finding HTML using regular expressions, it's ***very*** complex and ***extremely*** fickle.